# Powershell New-LocalUser not working properly

Tags: powershell

My script creates a new user but the parameters wont apply.

-AccountNeverExpires wont work. If I look in computer management under users there is a tick at "user must change password at next login". 
Also never expire is not ticked.

```
New-LocalUser -Name Test -NoPassword -AccountNeverExpires
```

Comment: `-AccountNeverExpires` applies to passwords. You are not setting a password. So that property will not even be active. There is no password to change, so the flag `user must change password at next login` is irrelevant.

Comment: I want that for the user "account never expires" is activated without a password. how can I do that?

Comment: That account cannot expire if it doesn't have a password. So by not setting a password, it is already set to NOT expire even if you don't mention it explicitly.

Comment: That makes sense but it is weird that under computer management the tick is not set. Is that alright?

Comment: I believe that checkbox should be grayed out and hence cannot be set.

Comment: Yes it is grayed out. However the checkbox "user must change password at next login" is set although I have the flag -NoPassword